# How to insert Country data to the MS Dynamics CRM Lead entity

Tags: c#, api, dynamics-crm, xrm

How to insert country data (`Address1_Country`) to the MS Dynamics CRM Lead entity?

I am using the Xrm.cs and Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk NuGet package. I would like to add a country data along the new Lead entity that I am creating.

I have no problem creating a new Lead entity, like:

[image]

And I am adding a country data along other data to the Lead entity, like:

[image]

But the country data does not get passed further to the CRM:

[image]

I have NO idea what is wrong. The `Address1_Country` data is `string` type. So I have tried also data like "DE" and it does not work.

However it is true that country data here is a special data - lookup one. I am sure that this and my problem is somehow connected. Maybe I should fill the Id or Guid in? But Usually in Xrm.cs those data are also Guid data type .. So I am a bit lost here.

How can I fill the country data in CRM via C# API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Country is a lookup type, you need to set there an `EntityReference`.

```
Address1_Country = new EntityReference("entityLogicalName", Guid);
```

So you need to Retrieve the Guid of the country you want to set there (If you are going to filter by name you need a RetrieveMultiple) and set that Id there.

This is the approach with Late Bound, I think you are using Early Bound, you only need to parse this to Early.

Comment: Tnx, I have realized that when I was check the internal (read: attributes) level of the entity.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why this is the answer. The Address1_Country on the lead is definitely not a lookup type. It is a text field.

Comment: Well, I am just guessing, if you could take a pic of the details of the field and the logical name of Country in that form, we should be sure about it.

Comment: Well the thing is that country data here is probably custom and, yes it is look-up. But you are right it is not the Address1_Country property. This one is as we discussed - native. @BlueSam you also helped me, so I also voted for your answer, so no worries. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to double check the field on the form is the same field you are referencing. Open the properties of the field on the form, and open the Details tab and check the field name.

My guess is that it is likely a different address field.

Another way to verify this would be to look at all the columns for the record in an Advanced Find view.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Right but "Address1_Country" field is from Xrm.cs? This should be the standard one Country in Dynamic CRM, or I am wrong? Is this custom data? Right now I am exploring the raw data and it looks like ... But I was like 110% it is native CRM data ... Country ...

Comment: Correct, but there is also an Address2_Country field or it could be a custom field.